# What is "sit" a table

Tags: terminology

Regarding this [feud](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/wcgrider-ben86-dispute-1627174/) going on between Doug Polk and Ben Tollerene.

Polk goes on about "how rude it for Ben to *sit* him at CAPNL".  This is online.

I take it *sit* just means take an open seat at a table Doug was playing?

I take it CAPNL is cap no limit.

Not really sure why it would piss Doug off so much but that is not the question.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQQbTTOBiOc&t=172s)

Comment: Can you highlight exactly where the quote you're asking about appears in that thread (or wherever it appears) so that we can better understand the context? I searched the first half a dozen pages for the word "rude" and found nothing.

Comment: @3N1GM4 In the video he made.  OK in the link *sat*.   Same question.

Comment: Where is the video? I don't think anyone's gonna trawl through a 1300 post thread to find it, so perhaps you could link to it if you want decent answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **to "sit" someone is to join a table they are at in order to play them**.

Also, "CAPNL" is cap no limit.

When Doug says "[you sat me at 500/1k cap](https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/showpost.php?p=50719781&postcount=6)", he simply means Ben joined a table he was at in order to play him. The nosebleed players often spend a lot of time sitting at empty HS tables waiting for someone to play that at the stakes they want.

I disagree with @mfcrocker that this is about an unspoken agreement for HS regs not to play each other or that it's about some petty wasting of blinds. People sit at tables waiting for other players because they believe they are good enough to beat anyone at that stake level. Similarly, Ben says "[I sit him at CAPNL because I'm a pro poker player and I think I can beat him](https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/showpost.php?p=50720268&postcount=9)" i.e. that he joined Doug's table in order to play him.

The issue here actually goes back to when Doug coached Ben over about four sessions sharing all the work he'd done on working out the best way to approach HUNL. The understanding was Ben would pay Doug back with his training based upon his work on PLO. However, for various reasons, Ben never gave Doug the coaching in return.

The reason Doug is upset about this is because he shared his best strategies and ideas for NL with Ben. He finds it unfair that Ben would ignore him for nine months then try to win money off him with the strategies he only knew thanks to Doug's training. He explains it in a bit more detail in [this part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQQbTTOBiOc&feature=youtu.be&t=11m51s) of his response video to the 2+2 thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have it right in the OP.

As to why Doug is annoyed? He likely believes there to be an unspoken agreement between regulars to not play each other and perhaps feels that by sitting him it's a judgment of his skill as a player. He may also consider it an attempt by Ben to waste his money on blinds and antes in a game that neither should be favoured in.

Answer (score -1):

To sit at a table means that you keep a seat occupied, but you are not playing. The more often used term would be 'sitting out' or something similar.

Comment: Not the context used by Doug or Ben.   Ben wanted to play Doug.